# Sql query to convert area in a common base unit(hectare) and then getting its sum

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table for units with the value of base unit and converting unit

Now i have another table which has value of Total Area and Acquired Area but the values are in different units 
I want to convert Total Area and Acquired Area into hectare and then adding them

Comment: This looks like you should probably normalize your table. Or is this intended?

Comment: I have not designed the db but i have to create a stored procedure to get the required result

Comment: why 1 bigha = 2.5 hectare?

Comment: @Alexander Fedorenko its a universal value 2.5 hectare =1 bigha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM((t.Total_Area / (u.Converting_Unit / u.Base_Unit) + 
           (t.Total_Area1 / (u3.Converting_Unit / u3.Base_Unit)))) AS Sum_Total_Area,
       SUM((t.Acquired_Area / (u2.Converting_Unit / u2.Base_Unit) + 
           (t.Acquired_Area1 / (u4.Converting_Unit / u4.Base_Unit)))) AS Sum_Acquired_Area, 
       MAX(u4.Base_UnitCode) AS Base_Unit
FROM dbo.Total t JOIN dbo.Units u ON t.Total_Area_UnitCode = u.Unit_Name                 
                 JOIN dbo.Units u2 ON t.Acquired_Area_UnitCode = u2.Unit_Name
                 JOIN dbo.Units u3 ON t.Total_Area_UnitCode1 = u3.Unit_Name
                 JOIN dbo.Units u4 ON t.Acquired_Area_UnitCode1 = u4.Unit_Name
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c2efc/11/0)

Comment: thnx for the answer @Alexander Fedorenko let me try that and i will mark ur answer.Little change required is that i want two columns (Total Area+TotalArea1) and (AcquiredArea+AcquiredArea1) but i will do that..thnx a lot

Comment: thnx @Alexander Fedorenko i know already i have taken you much effort but i just want a slight change in this query..do u want to give it a try

Answer (score 1):

So, assuming you can't fix the data structures:

```
SELECT Total_Area * TotalConvertingTable.Base_Unit / TotalConvertingTable.Converting_Unit AS TotalHectareArea
       , Acquired_Area * AcquiredConvertingTable.Base_Unit / AcquiredConvertingTable.Converting_Unit AS AcquiredHectareArea
     FROM
         AreaTable
     INNER JOIN
         ConvertingTable AS TotalConvertingTable
     ON
         AreaTable.Total_Area_Unit_Code = TotalConvertingTable.Unit_Name
     INNER JOIN
         ConvertingTable AS AcquiredConvertingTable
     ON
         AreaTable.Acquired_Area_Unit_Code = AcquiredConvertingTable.Unit_Name
```

AreaTable is the second listed table in your question. ConvertingTable the first.

We join the Areas to the Converting table to get the conversion factor, and then multiply the source unit by the conversion factor to get the output in Hectares.

We have also assumed that the Converting Table only includes base units of Hectares, you can filter out anything else quite simply if required.

To include the _1 fields would require additional joins.

Comment: can u pls explain ur query a bit as how u taken AreaIdentifier and how u converted total area and acquired area

Comment: There is an assumption in my answer that there is a primary key to join in your Area table. If that's not the case then you need a different query. It looks like the unit conversion is a little more complex than I thought when answering earlier, I'll edit for a better calculation

Comment: There is no relation between unit table and area table so no primary key. Please if u can edit your answer @james

Comment: what i think is calculation may be like if total area is in Hectare then "conversion calculation" else if total area unit is Bigha then "conversion calculation"